# How perform an operation after that are passed a specified number of seconds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am absolutely new in JavaScript and I have some doubt about how to do the following thing:

Into a JavaScript function I have to perform an operation after that are passed 30 seconds. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function()
{
 // your code
},30000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)